# sql server Row Number with partition over in MongoDB for returning a subset of rows

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How to write below query using MongoDB-Csharp driver

```
 SELECT SubSet.*
 FROM   ( SELECT    T.ProductName ,
                    T.Price ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY T.ProductName ORDER BY T.ProductName ) AS ProductRepeat
          FROM      myTable T
        ) SubSet
 WHERE  SubSet.ProductRepeat = 1
```

What I am trying to achieve is

**Collection**

- ProductName|Price|SKU
- Cap|10|AB123
- Bag|5|ED567
- Cap|20|CD345
- Cap|5|EC123

Expected results is

- ProductName|Price|SKU
- Cap|10|AB123
- Bag|5|ED567

Here is the one attempt (please don't go with the object and fields)

```
public List<ProductOL> Search(ProductOL obj, bool topOneOnly)
        {
            List<ProdutOL> products = new List<ProductOL>();

            var database = MyMongoClient.Instance.OpenToRead(dbName: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoDBDefaultDB"]);
            var collection = database.GetCollection<RawBsonDocument>("Products");
            List<IMongoQuery> build = new List<IMongoQuery>();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.ProductName))
            {
                var ProductNameQuery = Query.Matches("ProductName", new BsonRegularExpression(obj.ProductName, "i"));
                build.Add(ProductNameQuery);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.BrandName))
            {
                var brandNameQuery = Query.Matches("BrandName", new BsonRegularExpression(obj.BrandName, "i"));
                build.Add(brandNameQuery);
            }

            var fullQuery = Query.And(build.ToArray());
            products = collection.FindAs<ProductOL>(fullQuery).SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending("ProductName")).ToList();
            if (topOneOnly)
            {
                var tmpProducts = new List<ProductOL>();
                foreach (var item in products)
                {
                    if (tmpProducts.Any(x => x.ProductName== item.ProductName)) { }
                    else
                        tmpProducts.Add(item);
                }
                products = tmpProducts;
            }
            return products;
        }
```

Comment: How are you querying MongoDB by way of SQL Server? This doesn't look like a MongoDB question.

Comment: @Stennie See the fun from the [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24812178/2313887). But what you say is true as there should be "at least" an attempt to work with MongoDB rather than post "Please translate my SQL". Still we may try, even though I wish people would make an effort.

Comment: Ah, this looks like a duplicate of your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812178/). I would recommend starting with the [MongoDB C# Tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/) as the query syntax is unrelated to SQL.

Comment: @Stennie i don't understand what you meant by "starting with the MongoDB C# Tutorial as the query syntax is unrelated" btw i added my one attempt

Comment: @Stennie yes this is duplicate, what can I do, I was trying to explain the other "Neil Lunn" that my question was misleading, I would like to correct it, but he took it as offensive and was going on downvoting, so I am forced to create new question

Comment: @HaBo: you've edited your question. The original question posted here was "translate my SQL" as noted by Neil. Subselects, ROW_NUMBER(), and PARTITION are all SQL concepts so in absence of code I was suggesting starting with the MongoDB C# tutorial to learn how to write queries. A [good StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is meant to help someone who is stuck on a particular programming problem rather than writing the code for them. The community tends to downvote questions that show a lack of effort, but given your rep I assume you have some experience here :).

Comment: So is my question is properly framed? or you think I am still missing something

Comment: @HaBo: Thanks for adding some example code; that is the sort of information folks will need in order to help (and know what you've tried :). You should also describe what the problem is with the output of the code. I would note that the original SQL query is actually not very useful as it is very far away from what you would use in MongoDB.  As far as framing the question .. I'm still not clear what the issue is with the query versus what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: my mongo query works and gives me the right results. But that is not effeciant when I am dealing with huge data, so I was wondering if mongodb has any concepts like SQL Server for Row_Number() and Partitioning

Comment: Now who is the great person to down vote this question? would you please give your thoughts to down vote this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Stennie with the help of his answer I could come up with C# aggregation code

```
 var match = new BsonDocument 
                { 
                    {
                        "$match", 
                        new BsonDocument{
                            {"ProductName", new BsonRegularExpression("cap", "i")}
                        }
                    }
                };

            var group = new BsonDocument
                { 
                        {"$group", 
                        new BsonDocument 
                            { 
                                {"_id", "$ProductName"},
                                {"SKU", new BsonDocument{
                                            {
                                                "$first", "$SKU"
                                                }}
                                }
                            }}
                };

            var project = new BsonDocument{
                {
                    "$project", 
                    new BsonDocument
                    {
                        {"_id", 0 },
                        {"ProductName","$_id" },
                        {"SKU", 1}                      
                    }}};

            var sort = new BsonDocument{
                     {
                         "$sort",
                         new BsonDocument
                         {
                            {
                                "ProductName",1 }
                         }
                    }};

            var pipeline = new[] { match, group, project, sort };
            var aggResult = collection.Aggregate(pipeline);
            var products= aggResult.ResultDocuments.Select(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<ProductOL>).ToList();
```

**Using AggregateArgs**

```
AggregateArgs args = new AggregateArgs();
            List<BsonDocument> piple = new List<BsonDocument>();
            piple.Add(match);
            piple.Add(group);
            piple.Add(project);
            piple.Add(sort);
            args.Pipeline = piple;
           // var pipeline = new[] { match, group, project, sort };
            var aggResult = collection.Aggregate(args);
            products = aggResult.Select(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<ProductOL>).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

> my mongo query works and gives me the right results. But that is not effeciant when I am dealing with huge data, so I was wondering if mongodb has any concepts like SQL Server for Row_Number() and Partitioning

If your query returns the expected results but isn't efficient, you should look into index usage with [`explain()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/). Given your query generation code includes conditional clauses, it seems likely you will need multiple indexes to efficiently cover common variations.

I'm not sure how the C# code you've provided relates to the original SQL query, as they seem to be entirely different. I'm also not clear how grouping is expected to help your query performance, aside from limiting the results returned.

#### Equivalent of the SQL query

There is no direct equivalent of `ROW_NUMBER() .. PARTITION BY` grouping in MongoDB, but you should be able to work out the desired result using either the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/#aggregation-pipelines) (fastest) or [Map/Reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/#map-reduce) (slower but more functionality). The MongoDB manual includes an [Aggregation Commands Comparison](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-commands-comparison/) as well as usage examples.

As an exercise in translation, I'll focus on your SQL query which is pulling out the first product match by ProductName:

> SELECT SubSet.*
>    FROM   ( SELECT    T.ProductName ,
>                       T.Price ,
>                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY T.ProductName ORDER BY T.ProductName ) AS ProductRepeat
>             FROM      myTable T
>           ) SubSet
>    WHERE  SubSet.ProductRepeat = 1

Setting up the test data you provided:

```
db.myTable.insert([
    { ProductName: 'Cap', Price: 10, SKU: 'AB123' },
    { ProductName: 'Bag', Price: 5, SKU: 'ED567' },
    { ProductName: 'Cap', Price: 20, SKU: 'CD345' },
    { ProductName: 'Cap', Price: 5, SKU: 'EC123' },
])
```

Here's an aggregation query in the `mongo` shell which will find the first match per group (ordered by ProductName). It should be straightforward to translate that aggregation query to the C# driver using the [`MongoCollection.Aggregate()` method](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/ff0ba4c1-f2ab-d3f4-9b15-28a895285dc8.htm).

I've included comments with the rough equivalent SQL fragment in your original query.

```
db.myTable.aggregate(
    // Apply a sort order so the $first product is somewhat predictable
    // ( "ORDER BY T.ProductName")
    { $sort: {
        ProductName: 1
        // Should really have additional sort by Price or SKU (otherwise order may change) 
    }},

    // Group by Product Name
    // (" PARTITION BY T.ProductName")
    { $group: {
        _id:   "$ProductName",
        // Find first matching product details per group (can use $$CURRENT in MongoDB 2.6 or list specific fields)
        // "SELECT SubSet.* ... WHERE SubSet.ProductRepeat = 1"
        Price: { $first: "$Price" },
        SKU:   { $first: "$SKU" },
    }},

    // Rename _id to match expected results
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        ProductName: "$_id",
        Price: 1,
        SKU: 1,
    }}
)
```

Results given the test data appear to be what you were looking for:

```
{ "Price" : 10, "SKU" : "AB123", "ProductName" : "Cap" }
{ "Price" : 5, "SKU" : "ED567", "ProductName" : "Bag" }
```

Notes:

- This aggregation query uses the [`$first` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/), so if you want to find the second or third product per grouping you'd need a different approach (eg. `$group` and then take the subset of results needed in your application code)
- If you want predictable results for finding the first item in a `$group` there should be more specific sort criteria than `ProductName` (for example, sorting by `ProductName` & `Price` or `ProductName` & `SKU`). Otherwise the order of results may change in future as documents are added or updated.

Comment: your shell query is correct. But How can i write this shell query in Csharp driver?

Comment: @HaBo As mentioned, you need to use the [MongoCollection.Aggregate()](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/ff0ba4c1-f2ab-d3f4-9b15-28a895285dc8.htm) method in the C# driver. It should be straightforward to translate; you are basically creating an array of `BsonDocument` objects representing each step in the Aggregation pipeline. These [MongoDB Aggregation Framework Examples in C#](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/mongodb-aggregation-framework) should help get you started.

Comment: Thank you for that answer that helped me to come-up with C# code. But it looks like C# drive obsolete collection.Aggregate(pipeline); instead it is recommending to pass AggregateArgs to Aggregate method. I don't find any exampled online to construct AggregateArgs. Can you through some light on it :)